# Trying to get the inputted adress latitude and longitutde

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I really hope that someone can help me with this. I am trying get the longitude and latitude from the address that the user inputs(Ex: 1888 NW 14th Ave Miami FL 33189) and save that addresses longitude and latitude in the geofire firebase. I tried this code below but it's not saving anything. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong and how could I fix this. Thanks in advance

```
 your_address =  (EditText)findViewById(R.id.baddress);
        your_city =  (EditText)findViewById(R.id.bcity);
        your_state =  (EditText)findViewById(R.id.bstate);
        your_zipcode =  (EditText)findViewById(R.id.bzipcode);

        final FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        final FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();


        String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Uzers/location");
        DatabaseReference update = rootRef.child("Uzers").child(uid);
        String address = your_address.getText().toString();
        String city = your_city.getText().toString();
        String state = your_state.getText().toString();
        String zipcode = your_zipcode.getText().toString();

        GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(rootRef);

        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());

        List<Address> addressList;
        double lat=0;
        double lang=0;
        //7,3,4,6



        try {
            addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(address+city+state+zipcode, 1);
            Address location=addressList.get(0);
            lat=location.getLatitude();
            lang=location.getLongitude();


            geoFire.setLocation(uid, new GeoLocation(lat, lang), new GeoFire.CompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(String key, DatabaseError error) {
                    if (error != null) {

                        System.err.println("There was an error saving the location to GeoFire: " + error);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Location saved on server successfully!");
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("There was an error saving the location to GeoFire: " + e);


        }
```

[image: Error Message]

Comment: what error it shows..

Comment: @Hasnaian Sabir Thank you so much for responding. I see when I debug the app that it throws an error saying  There was an error saving the location to GeoFire: java.io.IOException: grpc failed

Comment: are you using emulator. test it on real device sir

Comment: @HasnainSabir I am using a real device to test this. What am I doing wrong here? Is my code correct?

Comment: your code is right sometime Geocoder block, and does tie-in with lack of connectivity. This is a know bug reported to Google, but unfortunately not solved yet.Cehck this link https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64418751 just make sure your main thread doesnt work too much. and moved all get location method to background thread.

Comment: Is there anyhting else besides geocoder that I can use. I need this to work for my project

Comment: Please add the entire error that you get and the structure of your database. Please also respond with @AlexMa

Comment: @AlexMamo I just added a picture of the error message.